# Access a specific attr on multiple select with a few selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

The current code, which will retrieve one selected option(there are 2 selected).

```
<select class="filter-selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
      <option data-path="all?page=1&type=3,4,6" selected>Type 6</a>
      <option data-path="all?page=1&type=3,4,7" selected>Type 7</a>
      <option data-path="all?page=1&type=3,4,8">Type 8</a>
    </select>

$('.filter-selectpicker').on('change', function(){
        var location = $('.filter-selectpicker option:selected').data('path');
        window.location.replace(location);
});
```

How can I access the specific `<option>` that the user clicked on and get the path attribute? Right now it will just find the first selected option.

My Goal is to redirect the user to a new URL when he clicks on `<option>`.

The selected is being added with PHP(checking the $_GET, if it's in the array -> echo selected to the `<option>`).

I'm using bootstrap-select, [https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/][1]

Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance!

***--------Update--------***

Instead of using echo "Selected" what I did is is `data-icon="' . $path["selected"] . '"` (if it's in the $_GET it will return icon code, in my case: glyphicon-ok).

Now, the issue is that the icon will be placed on the left side of the text, the solution is to edit the bootstrap-select.js

First add a class(myNewClass in this case):

```
icon = typeof $this.data('icon') !== 'undefined' ? '<span class="' + that.options.iconBase + ' ' + $this.data('icon') + ' myNewClass"></span> ' : '',
```

Next, change the order the text output:

This:  `text = icon + '<span class="text">' + text + subtext + '</span>';`

To:  `text = '<span class="text">' + text + subtext + '</span>'+ icon;`

And don't forget the CSS of your new class:

```
.myNewClass {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with multiple selections, you will want to loop each option selected

```
$('.filter-selectpicker').on('change', function(){
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
        var location = $(this).attr('path');
        window.location.replace(location);
});
});
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of it, but the issue is when the user clicks on option #3 for an example, it will stop the loop and redirect the user to option #2 path.